# Existence and uniqueness of a set in a family of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $F$ is a family of sets that has the property that for every $G \subseteq F$, $\cup G \in F$. Prove that there is a unique set $A$ such that $A \in F$ and $\forall B \in F (B \subseteq A)$.

Proof of existence:

Let $X$ be any set and let $F = \mathcal{P}(X)$. Then for every $G \subseteq F$, $\cup G \in F$. 
Let $A \in F$ such that $A=X$ Let $B \in F$ be arbitrary. Then $B \subseteq A$. This concludes the proof of existence.

**I am pretty sure that this is correct. However, the uniqueness part is bothering me.**

Proof of uniqueness:

Let $C \in F$ such that $\forall B \in F (B \subseteq C)$ (first assumption) and 
let $D \in F$ such that $\forall B \in F (B \subseteq D)$ (second assumption). From the first assumption it follows that $D \subseteq C$, similarly, from the second assumption it follows that $C \subseteq D$. Taken together it follows that $C=D$. This concludes the proof of uniqueness.

Is the proof correct? I am working through an intro to proving things, however, most solutions I found online are dubious at best.

All the best!

Comment: Hint: There is no need to introduce a set $X$ and put $F = P(X)$. For existence, take $F \subseteq F$. For uniqueness, a standard argument is to assume that there are two such $B$. What can we say when two sets are both subsets of one another? :)

Comment: Thanks.I guess that since $F \subseteq F$ it follows that $\cup F \in F$. We then let $A= \cup F$. Suppose then that $B \in F$, It follows that $B \subseteq A$. However, the uniqueness part does not seem to be in need of correction or am I wrong?

Comment: @JJH Can confirm my thoughts?

Comment: F is given.  You cannot set it to P(X).

Comment: @WilliamElliot I take it that you mean the same as JJH. I think I corrected it. Is the uniqueness at least correct?

Comment: Uniqueness is ok.  The first part is still wrong, you cannot set F to a Power set.  A = union F will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

$A:=\bigcup F$ is itself a valid set and as $F \subseteq F$ by assumption it's a member of $F$ (being the union of a subset), so $A \in F$

If $B \in F$ then $B \subseteq \bigcup F$ is pretty obvious by definition of the union, so $\forall B \in F: B \subseteq A$ is also clear.

Suppose $A'$ also obeys these properties. Then for all $B \in F$ we know (by the second property) that $B \subseteq A'$ so $A=\bigcup F \subseteq A'$. We also $A' \in F$ so $A' \subseteq \bigcup F = A$ so $A'=A$.